# Mapbox GL JS add raster without tiling

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, mapbox-gl-js

With leaflet with reference to this sample: https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff

I was able to host a GeoTIFF file on the server and access it without tiling.

Can the same be achieved with Mapbox GL JS?

I have been looking into Mapbox GL JS documentation however could not find any information on how to access GeoTIFF hosted on a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the layer as image source worked:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#image